# Return Pandas DataFrame from BeautifulSoup's JSON script output

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Using the below code, I'de like to return a Python DataFrame from the html output. Is this something that can be done from a package in Python? See web link for table format.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
r = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.zacks.com/zrank/sector-industry-classification.php").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")

soup.find_all("script")[16]
```

Output script:

```
<script>window.app_data =
                {

                    columns : [

                    { "mDataProp"   : "Sector Group"
                    , "sTitle"      : "Sector Group"
                    , "sClass"      : "alpha"
                    , "bSortable"   : true 
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                      "mDataProp"   : "Sector Code"
                    , "sTitle"      : "Sector Code"
                    , "sClass"      : ""
                    , "bSortable"   : false 
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                      "mDataProp"   : "Medium(M) Industry Group"
                    , "sTitle"      : "Medium(M) Industry Group"
                    , "sClass"      : "alpha"
                    , "bSortable"   : false 
                    }
```

The data contains this:

```
data"  : [  { "Sector Group"               :  "<span title=\"Index\" >Index</span>", "Sector Code"                :  "0", "Medium(M) Industry Group"   :  "<span title=\"Indices\" >Indices</span>", "Medium(M) Industry Code"    :  "0", "Expanded(X) Industry Group" :  "<span title=\"Indicies\" >Indicies</span>", "Expanded(X) Industry Code"  :  "400" } ,  { "Sector Group"               :  "<span title=\"Consumer Staples\" >Consumer Staple...</span>", "Sector Code"                :  "1", "Medium(M) Industry Group"   :  "<span title=\"Food\" >Food</span>", "Medium(M) Industry Code"    :  "3", "Expanded(X) Industry Group" :  "<span title=\"Food - Meat Products\" >Food - Meat Pro...</span>", "Expanded(X) Industry Code"  :  "75" } ,  { "Sector Group"               :  "<span title=\"Consumer Staples\" >Consumer Staple...</span>", "Sector Code"                :  "1", "Medium(M) Industry Group"   :  "<span title=\"Cons Prod-misc Staples\" >Cons Prod-misc...</span>", "Medium(M) Industry Code"    :  "7", "Expanded(X) Industry Group" :  "<span title=\"Funeral Services\" >Funeral Service...</span>", "Expanded(X) Industry Code"  :  "78" } ,  { "Sector Group"               :  "<span title=\"Consumer Staples\" >Consumer Staple...</span>", "Sector Code"                :  "1", "Medium(M) Industry Group"   :  "<span title=\"Food\" >Food</span>", "Medium(M) Industry Code"    :  "3", "Expanded(X) Industry Group" :  "<span title=\"Food - Confectionery\" >Food - Confecti...</span>", "Expanded(X) Industry Code"  :  "72" } ,  { "Sector Group"
```

Note: Too much data to paste here. I also tried the below, as other answers suggested a similar approach, except I selected all using:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("'.*': '.*'")
fields = dict(re.findall(pattern, soup))
print(fields)
```

Output is `{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is better ways to achieve this. But hey, it gives you what you want. Also it's better to use Selenium+PhantomJS for tasks like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

request = requests.get('https://www.zacks.com/zrank/sector-industry-classification.php')
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')

#Tweaked the string for parsing. It's ugly solution. I have failed with regular expressions.
#You can achieve this with way better way.
data = soup.find_all("script")[16].text.split('data"')[1].strip()[3:].rstrip()[:-7]

json_data = json.loads('[' + data)

def get_title(key):
    return BeautifulSoup(data[key],'lxml').find('span').attrs['title']

d = []

for data in json_data:
    sector_group = get_title('Sector Group')
    sector_code = data['Sector Code']
    medium_industry_group =get_title('Medium(M) Industry Group')
    medium_industry_code = data['Medium(M) Industry Code']
    expanded_industry_group = get_title('Expanded(X) Industry Group')
    expanded_industry_code = data['Expanded(X) Industry Code']

    d.append((sector_group,sector_code,medium_industry_group,medium_industry_code,expanded_industry_group,expanded_industry_code))

print(pd.DataFrame(d,columns=('Sector Group','Sector Code','Medium(M) Industry Group','Medium(M) Industry Code','Expanded(X) Industry Group','Expanded(X) Industry Code')))
```

Comment: That's a creative solution. How would you suggest getting it into a DataFrame

Comment: Updated my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

pandas comes ready for that

```
pd.read_html('https://www.zacks.com/zrank/sector-industry-classification.php')
```

Comment: That's helpful, but it unfortunately does not return the script table with industry codes. See `soup.find_all("script")[16]` data.